# `write /dev/stdout: broken pipe` when calling docker run from python

Tags: python, docker

I have given python script :

```py
import os

os.popen(f'docker run --rm -t --link mosquitto-server ruimarinho/mosquitto mosquitto_pub -h mosquitto-server -t "test_topic" -m "{message}"')
```

Now, this script works as expected, docker command is executed, but every time i run this line given error appears in terminal:

`write /dev/stdout: broken pipe`

Can someone please help me get rid of it? I did search for solution but every post is about docker only and no  already posted solution works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.system()` if you're not going to read the pipes opened by `os.popen()`. Using `os.system()` will not redirect output, though. If you need that, you could try e.g. `subprocess.check_output()` (which reads them for you).